# Why does a method call slows down everything?

Tags: php, object, methods, slowdown

I have this small loop with a new object.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $ilen; $i++)
{
    $time = microtime(true);
    $row = db_row($res, $i);
    echo "(" . ($i + 1) . " / " . $ilen . ") ";
    $element = new dataStructureElement($row['code']);
    $elementT = $element->getTypeClass();
    unset($element);
    $elementT->setName($row['name']); // bad line!
    unset($elementT);
    echo number_format((microtime(true) - $time) * 1000, 1) . 'ms ';
    echo "\n";
}
```

If I leave out the "bad line" then I got this results:

(1 / 3000) 1.7ms  (2 / 3000) 0.7ms  (3 / 3000) 2.4ms  (4 / 3000) 1.9ms  (5 / 3000) 0.7ms  (6 / 3000) 0.7ms  (7 / 3000) 3.2ms  (8 / 3000) 2.1ms  (9 / 3000) 0.7ms  (10 / 3000) 0.7ms  (11 / 3000) 0.7ms  (12 / 3000) 0.7ms  (13 / 3000) 0.7ms ... (2995 / 3000) 0.6ms  (2996 / 3000) 0.5ms  (2997 / 3000) 0.6ms  (2998 / 3000) 0.7ms  (2999 / 3000) 0.5ms  (3000 / 3000) 0.5ms

But if I don't then I get this:

(1 / 3000) 1.5ms  (2 / 3000) 0.6ms  (3 / 3000) 6.6ms  (4 / 3000) 2.3ms  (5 / 3000) 1.3ms  (6 / 3000) 1.2ms  (7 / 3000) 3.7ms  (8 / 3000) 2.3ms  (9 / 3000) 1.4ms  (10 / 3000) 1.3ms  (11 / 3000) 1.3ms  (12 / 3000) 1.5ms  (13 / 3000) 1.2ms ... (2995 / 3000) 14.2ms  (2996 / 3000) 14.3ms  (2997 / 3000) 13.8ms  (2998 / 3000) 13.9ms  (2999 / 3000) 14.2ms  (3000 / 3000) 14.7ms

And that's how this bad method looks like:

```
public function setName($name)
{
/*
    I've deleted the usefull stuff like writing into a database 
    to track down the problem. But nothing changed in the behavior.
*/
}
```

I'm out of ideas ... don't ask about the unsets. New objects have the same impact if they aren't distroyed afterwards.

PHP Version: 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.20
(This is the only version I can use. I can not upgrade/update. Installing a newer version under Plesk is hard as hell and I this maybe wouldn't solve my problem.)

Thank you :)

Comment: A setter method that does not set anything?

Comment: I have thrown out everything to track down my problem. But kicking out everything didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Measuring the time only of this method has no influence.